# What convention in Concordion allows for automated generation of Breadcrumbs?

Tags: breadcrumbs, concordion

I am starting to play with [Concordion](http://www.concordion.org/) to create some tests for a small piece of code I am developing. In the example, it states ["If you use the right conventions, Concordion will automatically insert breadcrumbs for you."](http://www.concordion.org/Example.html). But, I can not find an explicit description of these conventions.

Comment: I posted the same question to the Concordion group on Yahoo. I'll post any answers I get here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the [link](http://www.concordion.org/dist/1.4.1/test-output/concordion/spec/concordion/results/breadcrumbs/Breadcrumbs.html) above, also read [How are breadcrumbs determined?](http://www.concordion.org/dist/1.4.1/test-output/concordion/spec/concordion/results/breadcrumbs/DeterminingBreadcrumbs.html), the key are

- Put the Abc.html under Abc folder
- Add Abc's description for the real descripiton
- Most important thing is to add related AbcTest.java in responded folder, please refer to  [concordion source code](http://code.google.com/p/concordion/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fconcordion%2Fsrc%2Ftest) directly